# Error in Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

While running my application using Sqlite i am getting the below error.

```
SQLiteLog(779): (1) near "SQXC31DLT": syntax error
System.out(779): DATABASE ERROR android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SQXC31DLT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID =? SQXC31DLT
```

Code:

Here is my query

```
   String query = "INSERT INTO MessageTable (user_message_id,message,title,message_time,mp3,userID) values ('" + 

              umsermessgid + "','" + Messages +"','" + Title +"','" + timedate+ "','" + musicmp3 + "','" + userid + "')";


                     sqlHandler.executeQuery(query);
                        showList();
```

Here is the remaining showlist() method:

```
 private void showList() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            contactList = new ArrayList<ContactListItems>();
             contactList.clear();
             userid=    mDataStorage.getToken(FirstActivity.this);

String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '" + userid +"'";              Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
              if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
               if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
              //  do {
                 ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

                 contactListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("ID")));
                 contactListItems.setmessage(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("message")));
                 contactListItems.settitle(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("title")));
                 contactListItems.setmp3(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("mp3")));
                 contactListItems.setusermessageid(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("user_message_id")));
                 contactList.add(contactListItems);

               // } while (c1.moveToNext());
               }
              }
              c1.close();


        }
```

I have checked everything but still i am receiving error

```
CursorWindow(1211): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.



   05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.example.universal.FirstActivity.showList(FirstActivity.java:330)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.example.universal.FirstActivity.access$1(FirstActivity.java:317)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.example.universal.FirstActivity$GetTask.onPostExecute(FirstActivity.java:137)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.example.universal.FirstActivity$GetTask.onPostExecute(FirstActivity.java:1)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-18 10:37:11.022: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody help me to solve this issue!! @Thanks

Comment: please post your whole logcat

Comment: you should use the **?** character only to format queries that have `selectionArgs` parameter..

Answer (score 1):

your query is wrong.

use:

```
String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID =" + userid ;
```

in your showList() function.

Comment: change to: 
String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '" + userid +"'"; and see

Comment: then also i am receiving error CursorWindow(1211): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.

Comment: ok last try:
String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM MessageTable WHERE userID =+ "'" + userid +"'";

Comment: are you getting anything if you try query hard coding? String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = SQXC31DLT"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30173/discussion-between-udi-oshi-and-priya2134412)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like the following

```
String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '" + userid +"'";
```

Or try like the following.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM MessageTable where userID = '"+ userid + "'", null);
```

Comment: using your code i am getting this error 05-18 10:37:10.992: E/CursorWindow(1211): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.

Comment: also may i know what is `SQXC31DLT`?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with your code?

This sql query should be the right query for your first problem:

> String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '"
>   + userid +"'"; 
>    (by Gunaseelan)

This error:

> Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows,
>   1 columns.

is because your using a false query. The query you are using returns only a number - the count. ( one column and one row)

The right query  for this code:

> Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
>                 if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
>                  if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
>                 //  do {
>                    ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();
>
> ```
>              contactListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("ID")));
>              contactListItems.setmessage(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("message")));
>              contactListItems.settitle(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("title")));
>              contactListItems.setmp3(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("mp3")));
>              contactListItems.setusermessageid(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("user_message_id")));
>              contactList.add(contactListItems);
>
>            // } while (c1.moveToNext());
>            }
>           }
>           c1.close();
> ```

**should be:**

> String query = "SELECT ***** FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '" + userid
>   +"'";

**and not:**

> String query = "SELECT  count(*) FROM MessageTable  WHERE userID = '"
>   + userid +"'";